# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 Clustering

Tags: nginx, wso2, load-balancing, wso2-esb

Is it possible to create one ESB node as a dual role as a worker and manager ? 
I'm using wso2 ESB 4.8.1 and nginx as load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy. This is what you have to do.

1. Forget about nginx and setup the ESB cluster. Lets say a cluster with one manager and one worker. I think you will be able to get it done by following the instructions [here.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+ESB) Instead of WSO2 ELB mentioned in the doc, you are going to use nginx. Instead of the ELB, You can set the management and worker node as the well known members. i.e. In both nodes, you set both nodes as the well known members.
2. Once you have the cluster working, you should be able to send requests to an artifact deployed to both nodes separately. Difference between the manager node and worker node is, manager node is the one who only commits to the svn repo. So, when you deploy new artifacts you should deploy them using the manager node.
3. Now you have to configure two sites in nginx. Lets assume you decided to use esbmgt.mydomain.com for the management node and esb.mydomain.com for the worker. In esbmgt's upstream, you only mention about the manager node and also you route the requests to the 9443 port of the node. In the esb's upstream, you mention both nodes and the requests are routed to 8280 (http) and 8243 (https). Thats because the ESB serves requests using those ports and the UI is exposed via 9443 (https)

I hope the above information will help you.

Comment: Where is the port 8280 and 8243 ports are defined?

Comment: Its in repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml inside the ESB pack. You can also do a grep to find it.